# Does repulsion occurs in a current carrying conductor?

Tags: electromagnetism, electric-current, conductors, coulombs-law

In a current carrying conductor, there are lots of electrons moving inside the conductor. Is there repulsive forces acting on the like charges moving ?(i.e electrons), if yes Does the repulsive forces between the like charges affect its movement ?.

Comment: look up skin effect

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In a current carrying wire, the current flow produces loops of magnetic field inside the wire.  These act on the moving electrons pushing them outward. This causes a higher density of positive charge at the center and an electric field pointing outward  which prevents a further separation of charge.
The power supply produces a separation of charge between the ends of the wire and a charge gradient in the wire which maintains the constant current flow.

Answer (score 2):

Current-carrying wires or conductors produce magnetic field around them, which exerts force one the other wire (via the moving electrons).
Any small force dF acting on small length dl is,
$$ \frac{\mu\cdot i_1\cdot i_2}{2\pi r}$$
where $i_1$ is current in first wire, $i_2$ is current in second wire, r is distance between them,and $\mu=4\pi\times10^{-7}$.

[image]

Force is attractive if current is flowing in same direction in both wires
And repulsive if they are flowing in opposite direction to each other.